# I'm having trouble with Markov chains

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Below is a photo of the problem I'm having trouble with.
[image: Original Problem]

Below is my work up to this point, however 0.38 is showing up as incorrect. I'm honestly not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[image: My Work]

Comment: Your work is correct, maybe they want a different form for the answer.

Comment: Maybe they want 0.3? @SebastianCor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing of the question is a bit tricky. They ask "what proportion **of the state 2 population** will be in state 2 after two steps?". This is equivalent to asking "given that we start in state 2, what is the probability of landing in state 2 after 2 steps?" In other words, you should look for the second entry of 
$$
P^2 \pmatrix{0\\1} = \pmatrix{0.54\\0.46}.
$$
So, your answer should be $0.46$.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be asking "what proportion **of the state 2 population** will be in state 2". This is $P(X_2=2\mid X_0=2)$, which you can read off from the matrix $P^2$ -- it is the $(2,2)$ element, which by your calculation is $0.46$.